# Difference between WM_CLOSE and SC_CLOSE

Tags: .net, winforms, windows-messages

I just want to know what is the difference between these two messaging constants. Which one should I use in `WndProc` method when overriding, to handle close button message.

Comment: You tagged this [winforms], use the FormClosing event.  Pay attention to the passed e.CloseReason, set e.Cancel = true to prevent the close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`WM_CLOSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is sent as a window message whenever the window is requested to be closed, by any means.

`SC_CLOSE` is sent as a parameter of a [`WM_SYSCOMMAND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message, when the user presses the Close button (or selects Close from the control menu of the window).

Which one you listen for is determined by which action(s) you attempting to intercept/deal with.

Comment: Suppose that I want to cancel all pending validations on the form and let the user close the window gracefully, what would I chose then?

Comment: If you want to do this *whenever* the window is closed (be it by the user pressing the Close button, or a button within your application asking for the window to close, or when e.g. Task Manager sends the window a close message), use `WM_CLOSE`.

Comment: An application can prompt the user for confirmation, prior to destroying a window, by processing the WM_CLOSE message and calling the DestroyWindow function only if the user confirms the choice.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm asking this just out of curiosity as I've just understood the power of Windows messages. Suppose I have a textbox in one tabpage, the validation in that textbox fails but still the user is able to go to the other tabpage. Is there a way with messages to stop the user from going to the other tabpage untill the control is validated.

Comment: @SohamDasgupta - possibly - but I'd avoid it if possible. I'd put a warning sign next to any controls with invalid content, and possibly a warning above the tab control showing "some settings are invalid", but let the user freely move between tab pages - it's a better experience for the user.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Lets say that other parts of the form are not usable until that value is provided. For e.g. in a Sales Order until a customer is chosen users cannot choose the products. In our case lets say it is mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

According to msdn, SC_CLOSE is one of wParam values of [WM_SYSCOMMAND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.

> A window receives this message when the user chooses a command from
>   the Window menu (formerly known as the system or control menu) or when
>   the user chooses the maximize button, minimize button, restore button,
>   or close button.

[WM_CLOSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617(v=vs.85).aspx) is a message itself.

> Sent as a signal that a window or an application should terminate.

So, when window receives WM_SYSCOMMAND with parameter value SC_CLOSE, then you can close window (send WM_CLOSE message).

UPDATE (if you want to let user to close the window gracefully):
An application can prompt the user for confirmation, prior to destroying a window, by processing the WM_CLOSE message and calling the DestroyWindow function only if the user confirms the choice.

BTW if you use C#, you can handle `FormClosing` event and do you work there. If you need to cancel closing, then just set `e.Cancel = true` for event argument.

Comment: I've used form closing event but that just fires off after the validation event on the control has executed which is not the behavior I want. I just came across this [article](http://radio-weblogs.com/0101134/2003/06/09.html) which explained this hack

Comment: Actually FormClosing event comes **before** validation. Validation occured because textBox loses focus when messagebox "Close window?" displayed. Just set `CausesValidation = false;` at the top of your FormClosing event handler (before you show messagebox).